# When is it right to be biased?

Tags: cognitive-bias, emotional-bias

When is it right to be biased?

*Bias* often has a negative connotation, suggesting that it's an "unfair, unreal tendency or deviation". However, it's possible that some forms of "inclination" are in fact "true".

So is being biased towards something right, if the bias is true?

Comment: Being inclined towards ideas for good reasons, like evidence and sound arguments, is not what is called ["bias"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias). The negative connotation is baked into the definition, it is an inclination based on something that does not track the truth.

Comment: Sometimes make a choice fast is more important than make the optimal choice. It was particularly true before the age of civilization, when humans lived in the wilderness. Back then be wary of the neighbor tribe, scared of obscure places, etc could save your life, which made being biased a valuable trait for natural selection. Nowadays it can still be useful from time to time, but not as much as it was back then. However a few hundred years of relative safety weight nothing against millennia of evolution.

Comment: @Conifold But if it's bias in "statistical outlier" -sense then "being biased" depends on where one stands. If you are an outlier, then your bias is not the same as the median's. This should suggest that on a large possible cases "being *negatively* biased in opinion" is not trivial, since it depends on one's "point of reference".

Comment: Sure. So far as there is disagreement as to which reasons are "good" one person's bias can be another person's rationality. However, there is presumably some objective sense in which evidence is compelling and arguments are sound, so it is not *being* biased that depends on where one stands, only being *called* biased. In other words, bias is never right even if we cannot always *tell* what is or is not bias. But it can be right to act in a way that is called "biased" by some, or even most.

Comment: This has very likely been asked before, but why, on Philosophy Stack, is it considered normal/O.K. to answer questions in the comments? Surely one of the the purposes of using the answer box is to enable more useful material to be discoverable by searches. Many, many of the comments I read on this stack qualify as (often excellent) answers.

Comment: @Futilitarian Mostly because the OP language here is typically too vague and context-free to discern what the question really is. What is or is not an answer, and even what is or is not the question is only visible in hindsight, if ever, including to the OP. They only know what they meant when they see it spelled out, often after cycles of trial and error.

Comment: Hmmm. Well, most of the comments here were better than my answer, so I've deleted it. : )   I reckon there's definitely scope for an improved answer/comment ratio, especially when it comes to relatively clear questions such as this. First-world problem. I'll live.

Comment: @futilitarian a user once summed it up pretty well (and I think it was precisely Conifold) "if my answer is short enough to fit in a comment, it's not worthy of being proposed as answer and I put it in the comments". Some other criteria much apply, for example here my comment is not about philosophy but evolutionary biology.

Comment: @Conifold In reply to the first comment. I would wish to remind us here though that there doesn't necessarily exist objective information. Therefore the criteria for soundness may well be subjective after all, or i.e. biased.

Answer (score -1):

This question is unfortunately worded, because it conflates 'prejudice' and 'preference' under the single term 'bias'. The term 'bias' only has a negative connotation - and in fact, is generally only used — when it refers to people, groups, or human activities and events. One doesn't have a bias for or against broccoli, basalt, Pepsi, Priuses, or any other *object*. one might like an object or dislike it, gravitate towards it or avoid it, or otherwise have tastes and preferences about it. One only has biases against *subjects*: other people in their similarities and dissimilarities to oneself. One might approve of people who eat broccoli, or despise people who drive Priuses; the bias is against the subject who interacts with the object, not against the object being interacted with.

To dig into it a bit, we can effectively define a 'bias' as an effort to reduce a *subject* to the status of an *object*, stripping the subject of its inherent uniqueness and evaluating it as though it were merely a matter of preference (as though the statements "I don't like broccoli" and "I don't like Muslims" were morally and intellectually equivalent). One is entitled to lump all broccoli together and approve or disapprove, because all broccoli is (more or less) The same. One is *not* entitled to lump together group of humans and dictate they are good or bad as a group, because human subjectivity grants each human uniqueness and value in their own right.